# Google app engine vs appscale

Tags: google-app-engine, appscale

What is the advantage of using appscale when I can locally run app engine project on the server and forward it to my server's external IP to open it to the internet.
Also the resource requirement of appscale is way higher than that of the app engine.

Comment: well, one advantage of using appscale is, it works in china :) 
when you say locally run app engine, you mean in your local computer? That won't scale.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure I follow your question: AppScale allows you to run your app engine up on premise, or on another cloud provider if you so desire. How can you do that from GAE? Also usually our cost/requirements are cheaper for medium/large projects.